# Erro no HTML: "There are multiple root elements"

Tags: html

Estou subindo um projeto para a VTEX, mas ao fazer o upload, ela acusa um erro de múltiplos elementos:

> There are multiple root elements. Line 3, position 6.

Todos os exemplos que eu vi não me serviram, alguém consegue me ajudar?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:vtex="http://www.vtex.com.br/2009/vtex-common" xmlns:vtex.cmc="http://www.vtex.com.br/2009/vtex-commerce" lang="pt-br"/>
  <head>
    <title>Teste</title>
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href="css/layout.css" /> <!-- CSS das div's -->
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"/>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <!-- Biblioetca JQuery -->             
  </head>
</html>
```

Comment: Está faltando código aí não é? a tag <html> não é fechada.

Comment: Qual página template está tentando subir?

Comment: é apenas um exemplo, esqueci de fechar aqui, mas de tudo que tentei, ele sempre acusa na linha do <head>

Comment: CMS> HTML TEMPLATES

Comment: A tag <head/> está errada, ele fecha na primeira e na ultima tag

Comment: @AlexandreCavaloti isso eu já corrigi, mas ainda persiste o erro

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66893/discussion-between-alexandre-cavaloti-and-mateus-alcantara).

Answer (score 2):

Sua tag `<html>` (Linha 2) está fechada. Como ela deveria ser a tag raiz de seu HTML, cada tag após ela é tratada como uma outra tag com o mesmo nivel hierarquico dela. Daí a mensagem "Multiple **root** elements".

Para corrigir, troque a `/>` por `>` de modo a abrí-la para que o `</html>` ao final do arquivo a feche, formando um único elemento raiz.